# Why in an AllowAny view of Django I get 401 Unauthorized using Firefox but not using Edge or Postman?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, backend, django-rest-knox

I'm using knox LoginView to make the login of my backend. This is the code of the view:

```py
class Login(LoginView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)
        return super(Login, self).post(request, format=None)
```

When I execute my frontend (developed with angular) and try to login using Microsoft Edge everything works fine. I get the token and save it in local. Same result if I execute a POST using Postman. But, If I try to do the same using Firefox I receive 401 Unauthorized with this JSON:

```json
{"detail":"Invalid token."}
```

Why does it ask for a token if its an AllowAny view? Why does it work in Edge and Postman but not in Firefox?

More data:

This is the authentication class in settings.py:

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

EDIT: Actually, it works usign Firefox Developer Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem cleaning cookies.

Comment: Cleaning cookies doesn't work for me. I solved by rebooting.